# How to convert vector to scalar, for switch statement?

Tags: matlab, switch-statement, ocr, scalar

I have a code to test a network for OCR process. 
Here it is:

```
%% Set new target data (data testing) data2 = fetest8; % data2 = fetest2; % data2 = fetest3; targetx = zeros(1,204); targetx (:,1:50) = 1; targetx (:,51:52) = 2; targetx (:,53:62) = 3; targetx (:,63:82) = 4; targetx (:,83) = 5; targetx (:,84:85) = 6; targetx (:,86:92) = 7; targetx (:,93:95) = 8; targetx (:,96:105) = 9; targetx (:,106) = 10; targetx (:,107:111) = 11; targetx (:,112:116) = 12; targetx (:,117:126) = 13; targetx (:,127:176) = 14; targetx (:,177) = 15; targetx (:,178:180) = 16; targetx (:,181) = 17; targetx (:,182:201) = 18; targetx (:,202:204) = 19;

prediksi = round(sim (net, data2)); %contain target in matrix, data type: double

switch (prediksi)
    case '1'
        fprintf ('Alif\n');
    case '2'
        fprintf ('Baa\n');
    case '3'
        fprintf ('Haaa\n'); 
    case '4'
        fprintf ('Daal\n');
    case '5'
        fprintf ('Raa\n');
    case '6'
        fprintf ('Siin\n');
    case '7'
        fprintf ('Saad\n');
    case '8'
        fprintf ('Thaaa\n');
    case '9'
        fprintf ('Ayn\n');
    case '10'
        fprintf ('Faa\n');
    case '11'
        fprintf ('Gaaf\n');
    case '12'
        fprintf ('Kaaf\n'); 
    case '13'
        fprintf ('Laam\n'); 
    case '14'
        fprintf ('Miim\n');
    case '15'
        fprintf ('Nuun\n');
    case '16'
        fprintf ('Haa\n');
    case '17'
        fprintf ('Waaw\n');
    case '18'
        fprintf ('Yaa\n');
    case '19'
        fprintf ('Kaaf\n');
    otherwise
        fprintf ('X\n');    
end
```

Screenshoot of prediksi:
[image]

1 until 204, prediksi 1x24 double.

[image]
I got this error: 'SWITCH expression must be a scalar or string constant.'
How to fix this error?

Any help would be very appreciate.

Comment: What does `sim (net, data2)` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here `prediksi` will be a row matrix of size `1xm`. So cant use `switch(prediksi)`. Instead you have to use a loop and do `switch (prediksi(i))`. Here is the updated code

```
%% Set new target data (data testing) data2 = fetest8; % data2 = fetest2; % data2 = fetest3; targetx = zeros(1,204); targetx (:,1:50) = 1; targetx (:,51:52) = 2; targetx (:,53:62) = 3; targetx (:,63:82) = 4; targetx (:,83) = 5; targetx (:,84:85) = 6; targetx (:,86:92) = 7; targetx (:,93:95) = 8; targetx (:,96:105) = 9; targetx (:,106) = 10; targetx (:,107:111) = 11; targetx (:,112:116) = 12; targetx (:,117:126) = 13; targetx (:,127:176) = 14; targetx (:,177) = 15; targetx (:,178:180) = 16; targetx (:,181) = 17; targetx (:,182:201) = 18; targetx (:,202:204) = 19;

prediksi = round(sim (net, data2)); %contain target in matrix, data type: double

for i=1:size(prediksi,2)
switch (prediksi(i))
    case 1
        fprintf ('Alif\n');
    case 2
        fprintf ('Baa\n');
    case 3
        fprintf ('Haaa\n'); 
    case 4
        fprintf ('Daal\n');
    case 5
        fprintf ('Raa\n');
    case 6
        fprintf ('Siin\n');
    case 7
        fprintf ('Saad\n');
    case 8
        fprintf ('Thaaa\n');
    case 9
        fprintf ('Ayn\n');
    case 10
        fprintf ('Faa\n');
    case 11
        fprintf ('Gaaf\n');
    case 12
        fprintf ('Kaaf\n'); 
    case 13
        fprintf ('Laam\n'); 
    case 14
        fprintf ('Miim\n');
    case 15
        fprintf ('Nuun\n');
    case 16
        fprintf ('Haa\n');
    case 17
        fprintf ('Waaw\n');
    case 18
        fprintf ('Yaa\n');
    case 19
        fprintf ('Kaaf\n');
    otherwise
        fprintf ('X\n');    
end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, it give me an output, but all the answer is "X"
No one is match.

prediksi output is a matrix contain 1x204 data in range 1-19 (targetx value). 

I still really didn't understand. Your explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Can you please update your question with a screen shot of the `prediksi` in variable editor. I cant give you any explanation until I see what is in `prediksi`.

Comment: `prediksi` is not a character array, change from `case '1'` to `case 1`

Comment: @Matt You are right. I didn't notice it. Thanks for reviewing the code.

Comment: It works. 
The code give an appropriate output.

Thank you so much @Rijul